# ¿Cómo ingresar números y letras en un input y poner limite de caracteres?

Tags: python

Estoy apenas aprendiendo a manejar Python y estoy poniendo en practica lo que he aprendido hasta ahora haciendo un sistema de login. Quiero usar una contraseña de mínimo 6 caracteres y una letra, y aquí viene mi primera duda: ¿Cómo puedo poner ese limite para que al momento de introducir mas de 6 caracteres salga un `print` diciendo que el mínimo es 6? Por otro lado, en el código que muestro a continuación tengo otro problema, al momento de ingresar un texto o letra en el `input` sale el error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "codigo.py", line 30, in <module>
>     prueba2()
>   File "codigo.py", line 6, in prueba2
>     Request_Password=int(input("Insertar contraseña"))
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PruebaContraseña'.
> ```

### Mi código es el siguiente:

```
contraseñas=[123]
Archivos=["Documentos","Videos"]


def prueba2():
    Access=False
    Request_Password=int(input("Insertar contraseña"))

    if Request_Password in contraseñas[:]:
        Access=True

    elif Access==True:
        seleccion()

    while Access==False:
        prueba2()
        break


def seleccion():
  confirmacion=input("¿Que archivo desea ver?")

  if confirmacion in Archivos[:]:
      print("Acceso autorizado a",confirmacion)

  else:
      print("Esa categoria no existe")



prueba2()
```

---

Es apenas el comienzo, pero no puedo continuar sin saber como hacer lo que ya les dije. Todo funciona bien cuando solo cuando utilizo o numero o letras pero no las 2 combinadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Para hacer mas breve mi explicación responderé primero la pregunta del error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codigo.py", line 30, in <module>
    prueba2()
  File "codigo.py", line 6, in prueba2
    Request_Password=int(input("Insertar contraseña"))
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PruebaContraseña'.
```

Si miras el mensaje de error te muestra una pista de lo que sucede `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PruebaContraseña'`.

Este error ocurre porque estas intentando convertir a un entero algo que python no reconoce como un numero. Por ejemplo si digitas como contraseña el valor "123a" y aplicas la funcion `int`, python en realidad no va a saber como convertir eso a un entero porque no es claro que numero representa.

Entonces como tu requerimiento es utilizar una contraseña que acepte valores alfanuméricos, lo recomendable es utilizar un string (cadena de texto). Luego, como la variable `Request_Password` por defecto recibe una cadena de texto no es necesario utilizar `int`, y en la variable contraseñas podrías tener algo así: `contraseñas=["123"]` para que sean el mismo tipo de datos y poder realizar la comparación.

**2)** Ahora para la pregunta de limitar la cantidad de caracteres simplemente utiliza la funcion `len` para hallar la longitud de una cadena de texto y un condicional para preguntar si es mayor que 6, por ejemplo:

```
if len(Request_Password) > 6:
    print("tiene mas de 6 caracteres")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No se como no caí en algo tan simple como solamente hacer los datos de la array contraseñas[:] un string y en poner una condicional con len para limitar el numero de caracteres. Me enfoque en lo mas complicado y deja las nociones básicas a un lado. Graso error. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Pequeño inciso: Python no usa arrays, se les llaman listas. Es confuso.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo se debe a que estás tratado de convertir a int la entrada del usuario, esto por el 'int' al principio en:

```
int(input("Insertar contraseña"))
```

y como estás probando con "PruebaContraseña" te arroja el error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10.
```

Lo que podes probar es sólo con el input y luego chequear las condiciones (longitud mayor a 6 y que contenga una letra). Seguro ésta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/3239070) te orienta mucho mejor:

Comment: Hola Mario. Muchas gracias por tomar parte de tu tiempo para ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya te han contestado a las dos dudas concretas, voy a hacer algunas observaciones más al código. El error es simplemente porque intentas hacer un casting a `int` de lo ingresado vía `input` como te han comentado:

```
Request_Password=int(input("Insertar contraseña"))
                  ^
                  ^
                  ^
```

cuando estás ingresando una cadena con caracteres no numéricos. Ese casting sobra simplemente, `input` retorna una cadena "cruda" y tu contraseña debe ser eso mismo. La lista de contraseñas por otro lado debe contener cadenas, no enteros ya que tu mismo defines que quieres que la contraseña tenga "al menos una letra"

Dicho esto, unas cuantas observaciones:

- No necesitas el slicing de listas `[:]` para comprobar si el item está en la lista, no es necesario y es ineficiente ya que crea una copia de la lista (*shadow copy*).
- [No compares valores boolenaos con `==`](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). Cuando quieras comprobar si un objeto es evaluada como verdadero (`True`) o falso (`False`) no uses `if varible == True`, esto es considerado un "anti-patrón de diseño" usa simplemente `if variable:` o `if not variable:`.
- La función encargada de capturar la contraseña tiene varios problemas, primero en el `if` compruebas si la contraseña es correcta y si lo es haces que `Access` sea `True`, si esto ocurre el `elif` no se ejecuta. La clausula `elif` no se evalúa en el mismo momento en el que el `if` previo sea evaluado como cierto (eso es precisamente lo que la diferencia de `if` encadenados). La función `seleccion` nunca es llamada por tanto.

  Por otro lado, el ciclo `while` carece de sentido dado que lo rompes en la primera iteración con el `break`, bastaría un condicional. De todas formas considera eliminar la llamada recursiva y englobar toda la lógica de la función en el ciclo, por norma general la iteración es más legible y eficiente que la recursión.

Para conocer el número de caracteres o items de cualquier iterable simplemente usa la función preconstruida `len()`. Para validar que la contraseña tenga al menos una letra, puedes usar el método[`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) que retorna `True` si la cadena solo contiene solo caracteres alfabéticos aplicado sobre cada carácter de la cadena. Puedes recorrer la cadena con un `for`, pero es mejor usar `any` que retorna `True` si al menos uno de los items es evaluado como cierto.

Como casi siempre hay mil formas de hacer lo mismo, una de ellas puede ser:

```
CONTRASEÑAS = ["12345A"]
ARCHIVOS = ["Documentos", "Videos"]


def validar_contraseña(passw):
    if len(passw) >= 6 and any(caracter.isalpha() for caracter in passw):
        if passw in CONTRASEÑAS:
            return True
        else:
            print("Contraseña incorrecta")
    else:
        print("La contraseña a de tener mínimo seis caracteres y una letra")
    return False

def seleccion():
    confirmacion = input("¿Qué archivo desea ver?: ")
    if confirmacion in ARCHIVOS:
        print("Acceso autorizado a", confirmacion)
    else:
        print("Esa categoria no existe")

def main():
    request_password = input("Insertar contraseña: ")
    while not validar_contraseña(request_password):  
        request_password = input("Insertar contraseña: ")
    seleccion()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda. Gracias a tu comentario pude ver errores que antes no veía y mejorar mi codigo.